# How can I display rich/formatted text in lightningchart js?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I would like to display formatted text (using symbols, subscript, superscript etc) in the axis titles, legend entries etc of the lightningchart component. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you give more concrete examples of your requirements (rich/formatted text)? If it is something that you can't provide as a string, then I am afraid it is not supported. But I would still be curious to know of your use case.

Comment: Sure! For instance, I'd like to use subscript for symbols, eg. t₀ or P<sub>max</sub>. The numerical ones can probably be solved by using a font with the subscript numbers as glyphs, but for other characters it seems to be harder. I would also like to be able to emphasize a part of a title or legend entry using bold or italic.

Comment: t₀ for one seems to work, for example Axis.setTitle("t₀"). <sub>something</sub> or similar ones definitely won't be working in the near future but might be something we can support in the future.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that a javascript plot library doesn't support basic html formatting. Would it be very difficult to add support for html strings?

Comment: And is the same true for the legends, or is there support for HTML there?

Comment: This applies to all text LCJS components. It is because we have our own WebGL text rendering engine for performance reasons. Adding this is definitely somewhat complicated.

Comment: Gotcha. If possible, I would definitely appreciate a feature allowing some sort of text styling, if not full HTML functionality. You could for instance base it off of the API provided by the Unity TextMeshPro package: http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/

Answer (score 0):

Use [setCursorFormatter](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.2.0/classes/numerictickstrategy.html#setcursorformatter) for format text

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. The method takes a FormattingFunction, which returns a string. As far as I can see that string is not interpreted as html or rich text. Further, this function is for tick marks, but I need it for axis titles and legends.